# Unable to Edit/Create Pages at help.ubuntu.com

Tags: websites

I'm not sure if this is the best place for this, but I couldn't find a feasible way to contact anyone on the other site.

I followed a lovely how-to yesterday at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition, but because it is so out-of-date I had to spend most of the day searching for additional information about efi partitions. I'm getting to the point where I feel I'm competent to provide instructions on a few topics, so since it says in the [WikiGuide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WikiGuide) "This website is free for all to edit, and contributing is easy", I created an account, logged in and discovered that any page I try to edit or create says "You are not allowed to edit this page". Is this a glitch, or is it because I'm a new user? If that's it, how do I gain that permission? I could not find anything in the WikiGuide or on Google about this.